# Spring Boot API Calling returning status:200(OK), But No result is showing under the created database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

After executing the following code in Visual Studio Thunder Client I got the Status code as 200(OK). But the main problem is the data is not getting aggregating in mongodb database.

***Here is My code:***

**Student.java**

```
package MongodbExample.Entity;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "students")
public class Students {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String college;

    public Students(int id, String name, String city, String college) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.college = college;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository.java**

```
package MongodbExample.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import MongodbExample.Entity.Students;

public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Students, Integer> {

}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package MongodbExample.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import MongodbExample.Entity.Students;
import MongodbExample.Repository.StudentRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepo;
    
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addStudent(@RequestBody Students student) {
        Students save = this.studentRepo.save(student);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(save);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getStudent() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.studentRepo.findAll());
    }
}
```

**application.propertites**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=Spring_Testing
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mongodb.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongodbExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MongodbExample</name>
    <description>This is mongodb practice connection</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Here is my API Call screenshot in Visual Studio.**
[API CALL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnEEC.png)

**Here is my Mongodb screenshot in MongoDBCompass.**
[Monogodb bashcell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TKe5.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to post the relevant text/output/scripts as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I put @CrossOrigin on Top of StudentController.java